# C++ Boost Assio - Start in another thread

Tags: c++, boost

I have Boost Assio implementation in my project. Here it is:

Session.h:

```
#ifndef VIBRANIUM_CORE_SESSION_H
#define VIBRANIUM_CORE_SESSION_H

#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <utility>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

namespace Vibranium{
    class Session
            : public std::enable_shared_from_this<Session>
    {
    public:
        Session(tcp::socket socket)
                : socket_(std::move(socket))
        {
        }
        void start();


    private:
        void do_read();
        void do_write(std::size_t length);
        tcp::socket socket_;
        enum { max_length = 1024 };
        char data_[max_length];
    };
}
#endif //VIBRANIUM_CORE_SESSION_H
```

Session.cpp:

```
#include "Session.h"

void Vibranium::Session::start() {
    do_read();
}

void Vibranium::Session::do_read() {
    auto self(shared_from_this());
    socket_.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(data_, max_length),
    [this, self](boost::system::error_code ec, std::size_t length)
    {
        if (!ec)
        {
            do_write(length);
        }
    });
}

void Vibranium::Session::do_write(std::size_t length) {
    auto self(shared_from_this());
    boost::asio::async_write(socket_, boost::asio::buffer(data_, length),
     [this, self](boost::system::error_code ec, std::size_t /*length*/)
     {
         if (!ec)
         {
             do_read();
         }
     });
}
```

Server.h:

```
#ifndef VIBRANIUM_CORE_SERVER_H
#define VIBRANIUM_CORE_SERVER_H
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <utility>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

using boost::asio::ip::tcp;
namespace Vibranium{
    class Server {
    public:
        Server(boost::asio::io_context& io_context, short port)
                : acceptor_(io_context, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), port))
        {
            do_accept();
        }

    private:
        void do_accept();
        tcp::acceptor acceptor_;
    };
}
```

Server.cpp:

```
#include "Server.h"
#include "Session.h"

using namespace Vibranium;

void Server::do_accept() {
    acceptor_.async_accept([this](boost::system::error_code ec, tcp::socket socket)
    {
        if (!ec)
        {
            std::make_shared<Session>(std::move(socket))->start();
        }

        do_accept();
    });
}
```

And Here is how I start the server:

```
#include "Config.h"
#include "Database/MySQLConnection.h"
#include "Implementation/LoginDatabase.h"
#include "Banner.h"
#include "Server/Server.h"
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

using boost::asio::ip::tcp;
using namespace std;
using namespace Vibranium;

int main() {
    //Don't mind Logger::FatalError it's just for coloring!
    Banner::Show(Logger::Error,"AuthServer");
    Config config("AuthServer");

    MySQLConnectionInfo mySqlConnectionInfo(config, "LoginDatabaseInfo");
    LoginDatabaseConnection loginDatabaseConnection(mySqlConnectionInfo);
    loginDatabaseConnection.LoadDatabase();


    try
    {
        boost::asio::io_context io_context;
        Server s(io_context, 8080);
        io_context.run();
    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
    }

    std::cout << "Server Started!" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I have several questions:

1. When I start the server I can't see the message "Server Started!". I suspect that is because it is blocking my current thread. How can I start the TCP server in another thread? Should it be in separate thread or ?
2. The example I have implemented just return back what is sent to the server. Can you suggest any example of how can I distinguish different event messages? What I want to achieve is something like when I sent message starting with 0x001 to point that this is chat message for example or when message starts with 0x002 my server to know that client is informing that somebody has logged off.
3. I think Boost Assio is using Binary Protocol over TCP. Am I right?
4. Can you show me how can I send structs over TCP with the binary protocol ?

If questions are too much, please consider only question 1.

Answer (score 0):

> 1.When I start the server I can't see the message "Server Started!". I suspect that is because it is blocking my current thread. How can I
> start the TCP server in another thread? Should it be in separate
> thread or ?

```
std::cout << "Server Started!" << std::endl;
```

is called after

```
io_context.run();
```

io_context.run() will block as long there are any ongoing tasks. You need to call "Server Started" before io_context.run(), probably in Server constructor

> 2.The example I have implemented just return back what is sent to the server. Can you suggest any example of how can I distinguish different
> event messages? What I want to achieve is something like when I sent
> message starting with 0x001 to point that this is chat message for
> example or when message starts with 0x002 my server to know that
> client is informing that somebody has logged off.

There are many ways you could do this, but for ex. you could just set a field of your message to carry this information.

> 3.I think Boost Assio is using Binary Protocol over TCP. Am I right?

In your case yes, because your are using boost::asio::ip::tcp, but not necessary. There is also boost::asio::ip::udp for udp support.

> 4.Can you show me how can I send structs over TCP with the binary protocol ?

You could can just implement boost serialization method for your struct
*template 
void serialize(Archive& ar, const unsigned int version).*
See [boost example.](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/serialization/stock.hpp) or provide your own serialization (example to text) and send those data.

If you implement boost serialization, then you can pass your struct direct to asio functions, otherwise you have to send the serialized bytes.

Sorry, but having no time to write the whole code for you.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. Here: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp03/serialization/server.cpp they say that `async_write` will automatically serialize the data for me. So in this case I don't need to bother with serialization right? Also. If I send struct A{} from server I should have the exact same struct A{} on the client side, am I correct?

Comment: Yes, but here boost serialization library is being used implicitly (by providing serialization function in  void serialize(Archive& ar, const unsigned int version in stock.hpp). The & operator in boost serialization does both: serialize/deserialize, depending if input or output stream.

Comment: @VenelinVasilev In that example, the `connection` object provides serialization via Boost.Serialization, but that isn't part of Asio; it's [part of the example code](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp03/serialization/connection.hpp).  Asio only deals with transport layer protocols (i.e. TCP, UDP); it's up to you to implement whatever application layer protocol you want on top of your selected transport protocol.

Comment: Thank you @StPiere. Can you give any example of how to form and read a header packet and than the body of it ?

Comment: Also @StPiere in my example. The TCP Server is async, right ? That means that It can perform many tasks in parallel in same time?